# What are the different ways to use directories in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, directory-structure

I am getting directories from users and storing in databases. I really need validation whether they are correct. Right now I have the list of directories which can be used in a valid manner.

Only drive name - (with and without trailing forward or backward slash)

```
X:
```

Drive with direcory - (with forward or backward slashes and with and without trailing forward or backward slash)

```
X:\Test
```

Only two forward or backward slashes (without trailing forward or backward slash)

```
\\teela\admin$
```

IP address - (with and without trailing forward or backward slash)

```
\\192.168.1.13
```

IP address with direcory - (with forward or backward slashes and with and without trailing forward or backward slash)

```
\\192.168.1.13\test
```

Can you please tell me if this is the complete list or we can write the directories in another ways?

Comment: ..\..\..\..\this\is\a\relative\path

Comment: IP addresses as you wrote them there are just a normal relative path. You need to prepend `\\` to make them an UNC path. Also UNC paths consist of a server *and* a share name ...

Comment: Thanks Steve I will make sure people cannot enter relative path :) thank you so much

Comment: Thanks Joey I will make sure ppl can only add absolute paths and not relative...

Comment: You also need to account for environemental variables like %HOMEPATH% or %APPDATA% Check out http://libertyboy.free.fr/computing/reference/envariables/index.php

Comment: Thanks Mutnowski, environment variables are absolute paths but only problem is I need to check if they are set before use them. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [NDepend.Helpers.FileDirectoryPath](http://filedirectorypath.codeplex.com/) library to handle this for you. It includes a path validity check API.